# How to get output from gulp-ruby-sass task seen by gulp-useref?

Tags: gulp

I have some CSS that is created by  gulp-ruby-sass.  The resultant CSS file is referenced in the html used by gulp-useref to get my assets for concatenation, minification, etc.  The problem is (I think) that  gulp-ruby-sass hasn't written the CSS file to disk yet and gulp-useref can't find the file to include it in the build.  So this code:

```
gulp.task("compile-css", function () {
    gulp.src(paths.css.appFiles)
        .pipe(gutil.env.debug ? sass({ debugInfo : true }) : sass())
        .pipe(gutil.env.debug ? gutil.noop() : cssmin())
        .pipe(gulp.dest(paths.css.appDistDir));
});

gulp.task("concatenateAllTheThings", ["compile-css"], function () {
    var assets = useref.assets();     // useref package does the magic 
    return gulp.src(["./index.html", "./login.html", "./reset.html", "./confirm.html"])
        .pipe(assets)
        .pipe(gulpif('*.js',ngAnnotate()))
        .pipe(gulpif('*.js', uglify()))
        .pipe(assets.restore())
        .pipe(useref())
        .pipe(gulp.dest(paths.output.destination));
});
```

throws this error:

```
[19:06:32] Starting 'compile-css'...
[19:06:32] Finished 'compile-css' after 13 ms
[19:06:32] Starting 'concatenateAllTheThings'...
[19:06:32] Starting Karma server...

events.js:72
        throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
              ^
Error: ENOENT, no such file or directory 'c....\webui\css\custom.css'
    at Object.fs.openSync (fs.js:427:18)
    at Object.fs.readFileSync (fs.js:284:15)
    at DestroyableTransform.<anonymous> (C....\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\gulp-useref\index.js:81:61)

    at Array.forEach (native)
    at DestroyableTransform.<anonymous> (C....g\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\gulp-useref\index.js:70:35)

    at Array.forEach (native)
    at DestroyableTransform.<anonymous> (C....\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\gulp-useref\index.js:46:36)

    at Array.forEach (native)
    at DestroyableTransform._transform (C....\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\gulp-useref\index.js:43:15)
    at DestroyableTransform.Transform._read (C....\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\gulp-useref\node_modules\through2\node_modules\readable-stream\lib\_stream_transform.js:184:10)
```

How can I get gulp-useref to see the CSS file from gulp-ruby-sass?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To let know gulp when a task is finished, you need to return the stream. This way, a task with a dependency on a task that you return will wait for it to finish.

So change `compile-css` to

```
gulp.task("compile-css", function () {
  return gulp.src ...
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the hint to return the stream